# How to record audio stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, webcam, recording

I have a problem using ffmpeg:
when i trying to record video+audio from my webcam in result i got only video stream, wthout audio at all.
I have tried different codecs and nothing..
Maybe, someone can give me advice?

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270" -r 25 -s 800x600 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec mpeg4 -b 3000k -f avi D:\1.avi
```

Btw: virtualdub grabs both well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed the driver and codecs, use something like:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270" [path]out.mp4
```

A short explanation is given in [capture a webcam input](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input). For using DirectShow you have [this examples](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/DirectShow).

Comment: Hey. Yes, i red that example, but a) it don't works as-is, need to set bitrate. b) its outdated. I want to use dshow, like recommended