# Record device Audio and Stream using FFMPEG or

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording, rtsp, rtmp

I a developing an app in which I want to record Device internal Audio and stream the audio to other device on Same network.

I heard that FFMPEG and RTMP protocols provide the functionality to record and stream Audio. But I al unable to search any working example or demo.

I also searched about MediaProjection API, but it is recording the screen with Audio and then saving in local device memory rather than streaming it.

All I want to Stream the Audio while recording to other device on same network.

I followed following links for Audio streaming:

[Screen capture](https://github.com/Truiton/ScreenCapture)

The above link record the device screen and Audio and then saving in Local memory. But I want to stream to other device.

[RTMP Live streaming](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/663/android-rtmp-live-streaming.html)

[Record Audio stream using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487393/how-to-record-audio-stream-using-ffmpeg)

And this one:

[Audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494721/play-audio-rtmp-stream-on-android)

But there is no proper documentation or working example from which I get some hint, so that I can integrate that one in my app.

I know **ampme** App have this feature. As it is streaming device Video and Audio to other nearby devices.

I am stuck here. Please provide some info so that I can proceed further.

Comment: have u research rtc?  https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Comment: Yes, but I want to stream between Device to device not on desktop or PC.